# Why are callbacks created and used by a component commonly added to props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In ReactJS components I frequently see callbacks corresponding to UI events (eg. `onFormSubmit`) being added to the `props` object via the `connect` library.

Why is this done? Surely if `onFormSubmit` is created and only used by that component, it can be either private or added directly to the component?

Is it for testability reasons?

**Edit:** is it because access to the `dispatch` function of the store is controlled and made accessible via connect to avoid a component taking a dependency on the store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When used with `connect`, passing the callbacks via props allows them to dispatch actions, as you have suggested.

More generally, when the callback has to modify the state further up the hierarchy, a good way to do this is by passing it down through the props.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that there are some major reasons behind, which are related to each other:

1. Architectural / Design split components into Container and Presentational components.
2. Top-down data flow.

Above design decisions results in following rules:

1. Container components should keep the logic inside them and Presentational components should just display data. Of course that's the purest scenario, but in fact like you said it's possible to handle some simple logic in presentational components. However keeping that split is mostly done to keep Presentational components clean and in the same time to be able to reuse logic into various presentational components (if possible) due to top-down nature of react.
2. Speaking of redux plugged into react. You're perfectly right that only container components (the top ones) should be connected to the store. And only pass the specific piece of state to the specific presentational components via props.
3. Maybe also I simplify a bit, but Presentational Components should be more preferred then containers. So if you wonder whether some component should be container or presentational -> choose presentational and then in future when it's hard to maintain such decision due to system and complexity grow up -> eventually transform such component into container.

Comment: Thank you. Where did you learn your architectural approach to front-end applications?

Comment: I'd say that's the mixture of practice and trying to get the most benefits from different approaches / solutions from different more experienced devs. Speaking of React I like very much articles and trainings from Cory House - http://www.bitnative.com/, https://github.com/coryhouse